# How can i add a text to document library without any file?

Tags: list, document-library, list-view, library

I have documents and i already uploaded to the document library.
Document library only allows uploading files.
But I want to add text that do not have documents like a list.
So can i use this document library as a list ?
Or what can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look on to the requirements first on what you are really trying to achieve, currently document libraries will need to have a document as an item before you can update its metadata.

How about maybe instead of document library, use a list, then add the files as attachments. You can use [Pnp](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) powerful library for list manipulations.

Or If you really would want it to be document library, you will need a 2 step process, on creating it in a list, then on approval or status / metadata change copy the list item to the document with the list metadata, more on combination of custom script and msflow.

Above is only a suggestions, so, Hope the concept helps on any way.
Happy Coding! :)